# Automating Extract by Attribute using ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, modelbuilder

I have a shapefile with several forest data. One of the field is called *forest types*.

I would create a shapefile for each forest type so *Select* tool with an easy SQL Expression, such as "forest types" = 'larch' and then "forest types" = 'spruce', but I would automate this operation with ModelBuilder and not changing every time the attribute for selection.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried Iterate Feature Selection with forest type as Group field: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-feature-selection.htm

Comment: ArcGIS 10.5 has "Split By Attributes", available with any license.

Comment: @BERA , you solved my problem! I didn't answer so early because I tried your solution and it didn't work in the beginning. I think for a bug. After several tests, I made the shapefiles I wanted with your answer.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Iterate Feature Selection](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-feature-selection.htm) with Forest type as Group By Field:

[image]

Then pass the selection on to [Copy Features](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-features.htm). Use %Value% in output feature class to name the shapefiles after forest type.